# JAXB - Ignore an XML element

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an XML

```
<SubTask id="3">
            <state>enabled</state>
       </SubTask
```

There is a JAXB class with two variable "id" and "state".Now when I unmarshall the above XML, I don't want to load the "id" element into the Java object. How can I do this programmatically? I don't want to change the Java class.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your JAXB class has

```
   @XmlElement(name="state")
   String state;
```

then you should use `@XmlTransient` to skip deserializing of element.

```
   @XmlTransient(name="state")
   String state;
```

Other possible solution is, remove those field from the class.

Comment: Ravi, I don't want to change the JAXB class. Is it possible to do this programmatically when i unmarshall

Comment: @user2913809 what is the big deal of making above change ? why is it so important than your expected output ?

Comment: The JAXB class resides in a third party jar. Creating a new JAXB class will lead to more changes in the existing code.

Comment: ok, then override this class for unwanted field use transient annotation